# Madelung series error message: "constant cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values. "

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am a coding novice, attempting to use matlab to compute the sum of a madelung series expansion to a variable of my choice. I believe I have the basic theory down, but when I try to run my equation, matlab returns this error message:

> Sum::vloc: The variable {j,4}\ {k,4} cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values.

Here's the code I'm trying to input:

```
M3 = -6 Sum[(-1)^j/j, {j, 4}] 
-12 Sum[(-1)^(j + k)/(j^2 + k^2)^(1/2), {j, 4} {k, 4}]
-8 Sum[(-1)^(j + k + l)/(j^2 + k^2 + l^2)^(1/2), {j, 4} {k, 4} {l,4}]
```

The output is a fraction for the first sum, but the other two are in series notation with variables `j` and `k`. I would let get a single, real number output.

Any and all pointers are really appreciated! :)

Comment: No--this is Wolfram Mathematica 9.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM RESOLVED!

I had carelessly forgot to place comas between the minimum and maximum terms of my separate variables. Thanks, all, for your consideration.